# Difference between Sonar's alert widget and alert (advanced version) widget

Tags: sonarqube

I want to know the difference between the two alerts widgets in Sonar ("simple" vs "advanced version").

And where can I parameter the thresholds of alerts ?

Regards,

Stéphane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thresholds of the alerts is configured in [Quality Profiles Administration](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles#QualityProfiles-EditingAlerts).
The differences between simple and advanced alerts widget are the following :

- More user friendly appearance. Advanced widget shows all alerts in a
  clickable list. Clicking on the metric value you navigate to the
  drilldown view.
- Warning alerts are distinguished with orange
  coloring. In the simple widget if you have at least one red alert
  then all widget is shown red, even if the rest of the alerts are orange.
- Advanced alerts widget's last column    shows an indicator about how
  far is your metric from your threshold.